# Trigger takes current_timestamp and if older than 15 minutes, insert into other table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, timestamp

I have to make a trigger that takes a current_timestamp + minutes and says that if its older than the current_timestamp it should be INSERT INTO a new table.

I have been playing around with this for 8 hours now but can't seem to make it work. Anyone have an solution for this?

This was my idea:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER create_comment
AFTER UPDATE ON aflaesning
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF (TIME_TO_SEC(OLD.forventetSlut) < TIME_TO_SEC(NEW.aktuelSlut-900)) THEN
INSERT INTO aflaesningkommentar(aflaesningaflaesning,aflaesning_id) VALUES('That was too late',     NEW.aflaesnings_id);
END IF;
END;
DELIMITER//
```

It takes the TIMESTAMP (ExpectedEnd) from the table Loadings and have to put the row into the table delayedLoadings if the timestamp is older than  minutes. BUT it makes an error on the END IF//

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please provide the _exact_ error that you're getting? It helps others to help you solve your question.

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is the delimiter you are using. You should use a semi-colon after `END IF`, and then use the `//` after the `END` at the end of your trigger (which is also missing).

Also, unrelated to the error, I think you're conditional is wrong. You probably want to do this:

```
IF (TIME_TO_SEC(OLD.forventetSlut) < TIME_TO_SEC(NEW.aktuelSlut)-900) THEN
```

Instead of this:

```
IF (TIME_TO_SEC(OLD.forventetSlut) < TIME_TO_SEC(NEW.aktuelSlut-900)) THEN
```

So something like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER create_comment
AFTER UPDATE ON aflaesning
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF (TIME_TO_SEC(OLD.forventetSlut) < TIME_TO_SEC(NEW.aktuelSlut)-900) THEN
INSERT INTO aflaesningkommentar(aflaesningaflaesning,aflaesning_id) VALUES('That was too late',     NEW.aflaesnings_id);
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your IF condition to:

```
IF (TIME_TO_SEC(OLD.forventetSlut) - TIME_TO_SEC(NEW.aktuelSlut) < -900) THEN
```

Also, change the semi-colon after the last `END` to `//`.

Lastly, try removing all whitespace from your source and replacing with space and newline. Mysql can't handle tab characters in trigger source.